# Data didn't Fetch from public void onResponse(JSONObject response) using Volley

Tags: android

Here's my Code in `MainActivty.java` . While running the program, I added Internet permission too but I just got output as Error Occured! 
I want to display the data fetched from the url. Plz help me out!!

**MainActivty.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String data="";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HitButt);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


        button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
String url = "http://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt";
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new          JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,


           new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

           @Override
           public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
           {
           try 
           {
                      response = response.getJSONObject("movies");

                      String first = response.getString("movie");

                      String last = response.getString("year");

                      textView.append(first + " " + last + "\n");

                      Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());

                     }catch (JSONException e1) {
                                 e1.printStackTrace();
                              }

                     }

            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                     @Override

                     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) 
                           {

                             textView.setText("Error Occured!!");

                           }//void.onErrorResponse

                  }//Response.ErrorListener

          );//jsonObjectRequest

           requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

      }//view.onClick

    }//view.OnClickListener

 );//btn.onClick
```

}//onCreate

}//main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do

```
response = response.getJSONObject("movies");
```

while you have an array of objects

```
"movies": [ { "movie": "Avengers", "year": 2012     } ]
```

so you have to do smth like

```
response = response.getJSONArray("movies").getJSONObject(0);
```